# SPARQL how to retrieve records from a specific year using a date property

Tags: rdf, sparql

I'm new to SPARQL and i am trying to see how many records from a dataset were recorded in 2012.

Here is the query I have tried:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/date>
SELECT * WHERE {
?c dc:2012 ?o .
}
```

This simply displays a blank table. What can I do to get all records from the data set using the date property shown above?

Comment: What's the data look like?  Where are you running your query?  We can't really tell you how to filter dates if we don't know what they look like in your data.  Are they just strings of a year (e.g., "2012"), or xsd:dateTime literals, or xsd:date literals, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There is no tag as `dc:2012` in the DC tags. The simplest way is to get all the dates out and just filer them. For example,

```
Filter (?Date="2012")
```

Or you can use `dc:date` as the predicate, such as in,

`?x dc:date  "2012-02-20"`

So a query such as the one below might be a better idea. That is depending on what type your `?date` is. First try the query without the filter and see what type is `?date`, if it is string, this filter will work, otherwise you need to change the filer to match the type.

```
SELECT * 
WHERE { 
?c dc:date ?date. 
FILTER ( ?date = "2012" )
}
```

Comment: amended after your suggestion but again it is still blank, i think i'm still missing the fundamental understanding. Heres the query I just tried.   PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/date>
SELECT * WHERE {
?c dc:date ?o .
FILTER ( ?date = "2012" )
?c ?p ?o .
}

Comment: If `?date` can literally the string `"2012"`, then there's no reason to `filter`.  Just do `?c dc:date "2012"`.  In unoptimizing query engines, the unnecessary filter can be much more expensive.  But in any case, it's likely that the value of the date property might be an xsd:date/dateTime, etc., not just a simple string.